# 変数の引渡し方法についてc　#

Tags: c#

追記

```
void awake (){
    monstar = Getcomponent<monstarstatus>(); //外部から
    monstar2 = Getcomponent<monstar2status> ();//外部から
    int monstarability = monstar.attack;
    int monstar2ability = monstar2.attack;

    int monstarHP = monstar.HP();
    int monstar2HP = monstar2.HP();
```

条件　monstarHPかつmonstar2HPの数値が>0の場合
monstarが先に行動するとして、

```
int monstar2LEFTHP = (monstar2HP -= monstarability);
int monstarLEFTHP = (monstarHP -= monstar2ability);
```

上記の動作を永続的に行う。なお、どちらかのLEFTHPが<0になった場合その場で終了する

これはif と　forを使うのでしょうか？　または、ほかの方法を求みます。

```
int monstarLEFTHP = monstarHP - damage;// モンスターLEFTHP = モンスターHP100- damage 20
```

この繰り返しの処理をする場合
LEFTHP100ではなく、80になっているので
次は80から-20を引きたい。

Comment: `ref`とありますが、質問中のコードからはメソッド等の設計が読み取れないのでもう少し加筆してください。

Comment: 単純にmonstarLEFTHP を20ずつ引くのであれば、「monstarLEFTHP -= 20;」をすれば良いだけです。

Comment: `int monstarLEFTHP = (monstarHP -= damage);` とか`int monstarLEFTHP = monstarHP;...  monstarLEFTHP -= damage;` とか？

Comment: `monstar.HP();` の様にして`monstar` がHP自体をプロパティなりなんなりで持っていて取り出しているなら、一回の戦闘の結果のＨＰを`monstar`に書き戻してやる必要があるかと思います。そうすればＨＰを取り出した時に前回の値を取り出すことになりますよね。この関数内で繰り返し戦闘の解決をするような場合は、whileなりforなりで条件を満たす間、あるいは無限ループにしておいて、条件が成立したら`break`すればいいと思います。（その後ステータスの書き戻し）

Comment: monstarがHPをもっていますが、戦闘の結果のＨＰを書き戻すというのは、
どうすればいいのでしょうか。

Comment: 質問する以前の問題ですね。適切な質問をするのもスキルの１つです。もっと頑張りましょう

Answer (score 1):

だいたい以下の様にしているかと思います。

```
using System;

public class Monster {
    private int hp = 100;

    public int HP(){
        return hp;
    }
}
class Sample{
    static void Main(){
        Monster monster = new Monster();
        int hp = monster.HP();//モンスターの現在のHPを取り出す
        int damage = 20;
        while(hp > 0){
            Console.WriteLine("モンスターの現在のHPは{0}です。", hp);
            hp -= damage;//ダメージの計算
            Console.WriteLine("ダメージを受けてHPは{0}になりました。", hp);
        }
    }
}
```

値をメソッド(`monster.HP()`)で取り出していることから
外部のメソッドで実行していると思いますが、
HPは`monster`の属性値ですから書き戻す必要があります。
例えば以下の様に属性値をセットするメソッドを追加します。

```
using System;

public class Monster {
    private int hp = 100;

    public int HP(){
        return hp;
    }
    public void HP(int value){
        hp = value;
    }
}
class Sample{
    static void Main(){
        Monster monster = new Monster();
        int hp;
        int damage = 20;
        do {
            hp = monster.HP();//読み出し
            Console.WriteLine("モンスターの現在のHPは{0}です。", hp);
            hp -= damage;
            monster.HP(hp);//書き出し
            Console.WriteLine("ダメージを受けてHPは{0}になりました。", hp);
        } while(hp > 0);
    }
}
```

こうすると、モンスターの値を取り出し、ダメージの計算をして、書き戻すというループにできます。

Ｃ＃では、こういう属性値でprivateにしておいて直接値を扱わせたくない（のでメソッド経由でやりとりする）ような場合にプロパティとしての構文があります。
プロパティを使って同じように書くと以下の様になります。

```
using System;

public class Monster {
    private int hp = 100;

    public int HP{
        get {
            return hp;
        }
        set {
            if(value < 0){
                hp = 0;
            } else {
                hp = value;
            }
        }
    }
}
class Sample{
    static void Main(){
        Monster monster = new Monster();
        int hp;
        int damage = 20;
        do {
            hp = monster.HP;
            Console.WriteLine("モンスターの現在のHPは{0}です。", hp);
            hp -= damage;
            monster.HP = hp;
            Console.WriteLine("ダメージを受けてHPは{0}になりました。", hp);
        } while(hp > 0);
    }
}
```

外部からは直接属性値を扱っているように見えるので、単純に以下の様に書けます。

```
Monster monster = new Monster();
int damage = 20;
do {
    Console.WriteLine("モンスターの現在のHPは{0}です。", monster.HP);
    monster.HP -= damage;
    Console.WriteLine("ダメージを受けてHPは{0}になりました。", monster.HP);
} while(monster.HP > 0);
```

個人的にはこういうのを外部でやるより
`monster.damage(damege);`
のような呼び出しでやる方がいいような気がします。